# Pathfinding script

Tags: lua, roblox

I try to make a script for pathfinding but it doesn't work. It says "MoveTo() is not a valid member Path "Instance"" Is it because MoveTo() doesn't work and more importantly, what alternatives do I have?

> ```
> local PathFindingService = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
> local Agent = game.Workspace.StarterCharacter.Humanoid
> AgentRadius = 2    -- Settings Agent
> AgentHeight = 5 
> AgentCanJump = false
> AgentCanClimb = false
> AgentSlope = 10
> AgentMaxAcceleration = 1000
> AgentMaxSpeed = 16 
> AgentArrivalDistance = 1 -- end settings agent
> print(type(PathFindingService))
> while true do
>  if Agent then
>       local destination= Vector3.new(math.random(-571,165),5.5,math.random(-495,361))
>     print(true)
>       
>   if destination then
>       
>           local path = PathFindingService:CreatePath()
>           
>           
>           if path then
>               
>               print(true)
>               start = Agent.HumanoidRootPart.Position 
>               if start then
>                path:ComputeAsync(start, destination) 
>                path:MoveTo(Agent) --error
>                       
>                       
>               else 
>                   print (false)
>               end 
>           
>               
>           end
>           
>       
>   end
>       
>       
>   end
>   
>   wait(5)
>   
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `MoveTo` function on the agent humanoid not on the path variable. E.g `Agent:MoveTo(Position)`

Edit:
Instead of passing passing the path instance you have to loop through the points by calling the `GetWayPoints()` method on the path instance.

```lua
local PathFindingService = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
local Agent = script.Parent
AgentRadius = 2    -- Settings Agent
AgentHeight = 5 
AgentCanJump = false
AgentCanClimb = false
AgentSlope = 10
AgentMaxAcceleration = 1000
AgentMaxSpeed = 16 
AgentArrivalDistance = 1 -- end settings agent
print(type(PathFindingService))
while true do
    if Agent~= nil then
        local destination= Vector3.new(math.random(-40,40), -8, math.random(-40, 40))
        print(true)
        local path = PathFindingService:CreatePath()
        local waypoints = path:ComputeAsync(Agent.HumanoidRootPart.Position,destination)
        if path.Status == Enum.PathStatus.Success then
            local waypoints = path:GetWaypoints()
            for _, waypoint in pairs(waypoints) do
                Agent.Humanoid:MoveTo(waypoint.Position)
                --print(waypoint.Position)
            end
        end
    end
    wait(5)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing that problem, but now I have a new one "unable to cast instance to vector 3" (in my first version I was pretty dumb and should have seen that a path can't move)

Comment: @wc-thunder I just edited the answer.

Comment: I have done that but now, it says I can't get do "GetWayPoints" on the instance (probably the path),what do I do

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: @WcThunder remember the p is lower in the `Getwaypoints`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? (Also sorry for answering so late I didn't have acces to my account)

Comment: I just edited my answer. Try running the code.